# Вертикальный текст TextView Android

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Очень ищу возможность в Android  сделать отображение текста в TextView вертикально. Именно вертикально а не повернув на 90градусов.

Например:

H
E
L
L
O

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 8):

Может, и не самое красивое решение, но можно попробовать так:

```
<TextView
        android:ems="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="HELLO" />
```

Данный TextView выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

А разве нельзя просто буквы отделить с помощью `\n`, чтоб автоматически переносилось?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">     
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="H\nE\nL\nL\nO\n"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```